# Google's Cloud Speech API

Tags: google-speech-api

Does Google Cloud Speech support more than 1 language simultaneously???

looked in the RecognitionConfig dpec ( https://cloud.google.com/speech/reference/rest/v1beta1/RecognitionConfig ) where it specifies "languageCode": string
That seems to suggest only 1 language at a time can be specified. Bummer.

Is there a way to to get Google Cloud Speech API to understand more than 1 language?

i haven't found any article related to this

Comment: It requires language code because it's reallly expensive to also guess what language someone uses along with recognizing the phrases. You can try racing several requests for different language codes.

Comment: thank you very much..how can i try it with the code ?? is there special way or can i specify the two languages in the languageCode by using a delimiter?

Comment: the API doc doesn't say so, so I'm guessing delimiters won't work. Just make several concurrent requests and pick the one with better certainty score.